# How can I use vim to edit my command line?

Tags: vim

For example, when I'm entering a long command and I want to delete the second word, I want to be able to type `<Esc> b b dw`.

Comment: You can use the key combination `C-x c-e` to edit the current command using your system editor (usually vi in bash.

Comment: @mirk, that assumes you're using emacs mode on the command line (i.e. you've used `set -o emacs`).

Comment: @David, "emacs mode" is the default mode. mirk's assumption is perfectly valid.

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `set -o vi` to use Vim-like shorcuts.

To make this permanent, you'll want to put this in your shell's rc file (e.g. for `bash`,  put `set -o vi` in `~/.bashrc`).

You should then log out and log back in, or just use `$ source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: If you want to have this functionality in everything that uses GNU Readline (ie: bash, other shells, etc), create an `~/.inputrc` file with the line `set editing-mode vi`

Answer (score 5):

The best strategy depends on your experience with the command line.

I learned and got used to the default emacs-like mappings used in bash *way* before I started to learn Vim. They are too ingrained in my fingers for me to even consider enabling "vi mode". If you have more experience with bash than with Vim, I'd say that "vi mode" won't help you much. If, on the other hand, you have more Vim experience or are starting out with both, you may like the familiarity of "vi mode".

For what it's worth, I actually believe that "vi mode" is very close to useless. When on the command line, you are inserting text and Vi[m] is not better than others on that front. When you want to edit a command, "vi mode", with all its geeky shine, can't be compared with the power of a proper editor.

`<C-x><C-e>` provides the best editing experience you could ever dream of so why bother with the limited "vi mode"?

Try `fc` and `fc -l` for even more goodness.

Comment: +1 exactly same here... I love vim, but use emacs style for cmd line. if command line is long, I type `c-x,c-e` e.g. a complicated awk/sed "one-liner"

Comment: In vi-mode, `<esc>v` gives the same functionality as `c-x,c-e` in emacs mode.